# fill combobox with with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, d3.js

i have a select tag (id=combo) and i want to fill it with a json using the "Name" attribute.
but its not working. why?
thank you!

here is my json:

> var data= [{"Name" : "AAA", "Changes" : [ {"Lev" : 12}]}, {"Name" :
>   "BBB", "Changes" : [ {"Lev" : 77},{"Lev" : 14}]}]

here is my code:

```
<select id="combo"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var combo = $("#combo");
    $.each(data, function(index,obj)
    {
        combo.append($("<option />").val(obj.Name).text(obj.Name));
    });
    </script>
```

Here's the entire code with the csv file:
[code in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/c0Q1ajdxrJSvf5l2cAr8?p=preview)

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/wucxC/

Comment: Works fine for me, where are you declaring data? Put a console.log(index) inside your $.each to check if its entering the loop

Comment: Hi thanks, I updated the post with the entire code. it's still doesn't work. :(